# Conducting meta analysis of a single figure without control- but its not a proportion

Tags: meta-analysis

New to meta-analysis. I am conducting a systematic review and meta-analysis which is investigating a single health score across both interventional studies and observational studies in different patient populations. I am unsure of how to conduct the meta-analysis as the reviewed studies do not posses a control group where the figure is different and there is no pre-post effect size. I have the mean and sample size and most standard deviations from around 50 studies. I've read other posts but don't think its right to follow advice for prevalance meta analysis as the figure can be measured for each patient and the included papers are reporting means or medians of this figure for each population. furthermore the figure is not a simple scale [e.g weight (Kg)] it is logarthimic (dB). Am i over thinking this? any helpful directions or tips? Keen to use R if possible packages are suitable

Comment: I suspect from the details you provide that you are overthinking it. If you have means, n, and sd (or se) you can go ahead. Incorporating medians is more tricky. Software recommendations are off-topic here but you can always look at https://cran.r-project.org/view=MetaAnalysis for a list of packages or ask on the mailing list dedicated to meta-analysis in R https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis//

Comment: thanks i'll check those links